# url including extra word in path

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2 for web development.
 after deploying 
  it is showing url `http://localhost:8084/iland/` which is login page of my site
  which is correct but after login it is redirected to 'about' action which fetch user details  so in this case url should be `http://localhost:8084/iland/about`,
but it is showing url `http://localhost:8084/iland/pages/about`.
Here 'pages' is included, due to this change my css are not get loaded.
How to resolve this

my struts.xml for above is

```
<package name="myprofile" extends="struts-default">
 <action name="login" class="action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">about</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
   <action name="about" class="social.action.fetchBasicProfile">
        <result name="success">/pages/profile/about.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/pages/profile/about.jsp</result>
        <result name="login">/pages/pleaselogin.jsp</result>
    </action>
 </package
```

Comment: You have two duplicate results.

Comment: You should be using `"redirectAction"`, first of all--see what that does first.

Comment: What is the namespace of the package where `about` action is defined?

Comment: @DaveNewton After login it will redirect to about action

Comment: @AleksandrM Updated with package

Answer (score 1):

There must be problem with your namespace, so please check your struts.xml and change the namespace="pages" to namespace="/". this will resolve your issue. let me know if u find any difficulty

Comment: I was  not given any name space. Now namespace="/" has included. But this is also not working